# Change ListBoxItem Background color from within ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listboxitem

I've searched and came up empty, therefore I'm asking.

I found how to change Background and Highlight Background color of ListBoxItem using ItemContainerStyle.

But I'd like to change these 2 colors based on data from within my DataTemplate for Items.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution later on.

The only reasonable way is to define/redefine Listbox Control template.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be possible to do it with a list, I've already done this kind of thing using Datagrids.
Christian Mosers offers a good and understandable way to do that with DataGrid, you can easily use his datatemplates for ListBoxItems:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#rowDetails

**EDIT**

Have you tried to set a style aiming for ListBoxItems in your listbox's resources?

```
<ListBox.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
   </Style>
</ListBox.Resources/>
```

This should set all your items' bg to Blue

Comment: I'm sorry this is not helpful. Please be specific.

Comment: Just read the section "Row Details depending on the type of data" in the link I gave you, the tutorial should be clear enough (create a class that derives from `DataTemplateSelector` and then include in your XAML)  :)    (in his case, he changes the row background according to the object type, isn't that what you're looking for?)

Comment: I don't want to change the whole template. Template stays the same.

Comment: Problem is that Bg color in Listbox is defined inside ListBoxItem, that I can't reach from withing template.

Comment: Hi yes, but how would I changed this based on actual item inside ListboxItem?

Comment: If your items are found in a bound list, I'd encourage you to create two DataTemplates (I assume here that you have two different final styles), and then use the DataTemplateSelector described above to assign each item to a template. Otherwise, you can define two keys for your items upon generation, and then define two styles, this time aimed at these two keys and not at all the ListBoxItems. This should do what you are willing to do